# Producer and Consumer using Lock in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I got the Example from [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/06/java-lock-and-condition-example-producer-consumer.html). But there they just implement that example for just one by one. Mean first one integer to produce and then confuse and program stops.

Here is the original Example:

```
class ProducerConsumerImpl {
    // producer consumer problem data
    private static final int CAPACITY = 10;
    private final Queue queue = new LinkedList<>();
    private final Random theRandom = new Random();

    // lock and condition variables
    private final Lock aLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition bufferNotFull = aLock.newCondition();
    private final Condition bufferNotEmpty = aLock.newCondition();

    public void put() throws InterruptedException {
        aLock.lock();
        try {
            while (queue.size() == CAPACITY) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " : Buffer is full, waiting");
                bufferNotEmpty.await();
            }

            int number = theRandom.nextInt();
            boolean isAdded = queue.offer(number);
            if (isAdded) {
                System.out.printf("%s added %d into queue %n", Thread
                        .currentThread().getName(), number);

                // signal consumer thread that, buffer has element now
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " : Signalling that buffer is no more empty now");
                bufferNotFull.signalAll();
            }
        } finally {
            aLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void get() throws InterruptedException {
        aLock.lock();
        try {
            while (queue.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " : Buffer is empty, waiting");
                bufferNotFull.await();
            }

            Integer value = queue.poll();
            if (value != null) {
                System.out.printf("%s consumed %d from queue %n", Thread
                        .currentThread().getName(), value);

                // signal producer thread that, buffer may be empty now
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " : Signalling that buffer may be empty now");
                bufferNotEmpty.signalAll();
            }

        } finally {
            aLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

After that I modify the code and make it to work like,
First 10 Produce, then 10 Consume, loop running until program terminate.
Here is my modified code:

```
class ProducerConsumerImpl {
    // producer consumer problem data
    private static final int CAPACITY = 10;
    private final Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    private final Random theRandom = new Random();

    // lock and condition variables
    private final Lock aLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition bufferNotFull = aLock.newCondition();
    private final Condition bufferNotEmpty = aLock.newCondition();

    public void put() throws InterruptedException {
        aLock.lock();
        try {
            while(true){
                while (queue.size() == CAPACITY) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " : Buffer is full, waiting");

                    bufferNotEmpty.await();
                }

                int number = theRandom.nextInt();
                boolean isAdded = queue.offer(number);
                if (isAdded) {
                    System.out.printf("%s added %d into queue %n", Thread
                            .currentThread().getName(), number);
                }
               bufferNotFull.signalAll();
            }

        } finally {
            aLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void get() throws InterruptedException {
        aLock.lock();
        try {
            while(true){
                while (queue.size() == 0) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " : Buffer is empty, waiting");
                    bufferNotFull.await();
                }

                Integer value = (Integer)queue.poll();
                if (value != null) {
                    System.out.printf("%s consumed %d from queue %n", Thread
                            .currentThread().getName(), value);
                }
                bufferNotEmpty.signalAll();
            }

        } finally {
            aLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

After modifying It's working fine, producing 10 Random integers, then consuming those Integers again and again until program exist/terminate. But As I'm not master/expert in concurrency.

**So I want to ask** is there any problem in my modified code?

I'm feeling problem on my `bufferNotFull.signalAll();` and `bufferNotEmpty.signalAll();` placement, because that could notify waiting thread each time.

If there is problem then How I can solve? or If everything is fine, then please also clear my `bufferNotFull.signalAll(); and bufferNotEmpty.signalAll(); placement, because that could notify waiting thread each time.` confusion.

**Note:** It is just get and set code.(Producing and Consuming)

Output of Modified Code:

```
PRODUCER added 1062016967 into queue 
PRODUCER added 1204607478 into queue 
PRODUCER added 1865840177 into queue 
PRODUCER added -1279321362 into queue 
PRODUCER added -190570442 into queue 
PRODUCER added -1344361101 into queue 
PRODUCER added 609239106 into queue 
PRODUCER added -1480451794 into queue 
PRODUCER added 1905208395 into queue 
PRODUCER added -420578734 into queue 
PRODUCER : Buffer is full, waiting
CONSUMER consumed 1062016967 from queue 
CONSUMER consumed 1204607478 from queue 
CONSUMER consumed 1865840177 from queue 
CONSUMER consumed -1279321362 from queue 
CONSUMER consumed -190570442 from queue 
CONSUMER consumed -1344361101 from queue 
CONSUMER consumed 609239106 from queue 
CONSUMER consumed -1480451794 from queue 
CONSUMER consumed 1905208395 from queue 
CONSUMER consumed -420578734 from queue 
CONSUMER : Buffer is empty, waiting
PRODUCER added 1917580670 into queue 
so on.........
```

**Edited**
After thinking in performance I decided to to add if condition in both, `put` and `get` method before `signalall();` statement. ( I think it could increase performance even 0.000000Something ) But interrupting await(); could be a `deadlock();` Any help?

For Producer:

```
if(queue.size() == CAPACITY){
bufferNotFull.signalAll();
}
```

For Consumer:

```
if(queue.size() == 0){
bufferNotEmpty.signalAll();
}
```

Comment: Based on the output of your program, seems to me that it's doing exactly what it should do: producer puts things into the queue, consumer takes them out.

You might get more "mixed" results if you put the `while (true)` loops outside of the `try` / `finally` loops. Then instead of seeing producer / producer / producer / consumer / consumer / consumer you might see producer / consumer / producer / consumer / producer / consumer.

Comment: Original code behave more natural that your modification, exactly because  of Brian\`s comment. But original code uses confused naming for condition variables: `bufferNotFull` for check that queue **is not empty**, and `bufferNotEmpty` for check that queue **is not full**. Note, that In attempts to reduce signalling times(at the end of your question) you use natural sence of variable names: `bufferNotFull` with `queue.size() == CAPACITY` and `bufferNotEmpty` with `queue.size() == 0`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your comment. Ok understood. is there no concurreny/deadlock/hack/thread-lock/thread-safe issue?

Comment: @BrianMalehorn thanks I just decided to get 10 producer then 10 consumer, that's why I used while(true) inside try. So is there no issue about concurreny/thread-safe?

Comment: @BrianMalehorn I placed the while loop outside try/finally but it still producing same 10 by 10.. not one by one as you mentioned. code here http://codepaste.net/5os7di

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified code is OK.

As for possible performance optimizations via skipping `.singnalAll()` calls when them are not needed: it is sufficient to **emit signal only when condition is changed from `false` to `true`**.

For **producer** you can use:

```
if(isAdded && queue.size() == 1) {
    /*
     * Element has been *actually added* *into empty queue*
     * (previously .size() = 0), thus *queue become non-empty*.
     */
    bufferNotFull.signalAll();
}
```

For **consumer** you can use:

```
if(value && queue.size() == CAPACITY - 1) {
    /*
     * Element has been *actually consumed* *from full queue*
     * (previousely .size() = CAPACITY), thus *queue become non full*.
     */
    bufferNotEmpty.signalAll();
}
```

Note, that this way you are not eliminate unneeded notifications to the waiters(e.g., consumer can waits for element only for empty queue, thus only adding the first element will awake it). Instead, you eliminate calls to `.notifyAll()` when it is definitely known that **no thread waits it** (e.g. consumer cannot wait on non-empty queue).

Comment: why you used `queue.size() == 1`? this will notify only for one time. and after this condition no unlocked. I'm sure it could cause the DeadLock.

Comment: Any consumer can wait only on queue in **empty state** (size is `0`). `queue.size() == 1` will notify *every time* when queue transforms **from empty state** (size is `0`) **to non-empty state** (size is `1`). That way we never miss signals when they are needed.

Comment: I little confused, suppose producer will notify on `queue.size() == 1` after that lock will not released... so producer will produce again.. and then size will be up to 1.. So how produce can notify to consumer after size up to 1?

Comment: No needs to notify consumer about **every** element addition, *single notification is sufficient*. After being notified, consumer will wait on `lock` until producer releases it (after finishing seria of element's insertion). Then consumer will find queue being not empty, and will consume elements until queue becomes empty again (`queue.size()` becomes 0). And so on.

Comment: As I edit my question and add notify in if condition that's also fine? but could be problem when producer interrupted before CAPACITY size?

Comment: If you mean that your (modified) code already has branches `if(isAdded)` and `if(value)`, then yes, you can add corresponded notifications into this branches(BTW, original code does do this). As for producer being interrupted before CAPACITY size, consumer doesn't depend from that, so this will not be a problem in any case.

Comment: Just one thing to ask, thread just need notify once? even anytime starting or ending? after notify, already waiting thread will blocked until current thread leave the lock? (But if there is no thread that is waiting and we call notify just once after that notify will not be called again so what will be happen? mean if producer execute first then.)

Comment: `after notify, already waiting thread will blocked until current thread leave the lock?` - Yes, it is exactly so. If producer calls `.notifyAll()` (after adding first element), and no one is waitng at that moment, then no one can see queue being empty. This garantee is origin from the fact, that producer adds element and notifies with lock taken, and consumer checks queue with lock taken too.

Comment: I'm too close. Suppose Producer `notifyall();` but there is no thread/consumer waiting, So consumer will not blocked. Producer continues producing and once producer the 10. then producer will goes to wait(); and lock released and Consumer automatically will start consuming and get the lock without notify?

Comment: `Consumer automatically will start consuming and get the lock without notify` - Yes. Notification is only needed for returning from `.await()`. Returning from `.lock()` (with lock grabbed) doesn't recquire notification.